# php header and shell_exec

Tags: php

I have a couple of questions about a php script I'm looking at,

it has a bunch of code that I'm trying to figure out what it does:

the main portions are:

```
echo shell_exec("bash '".$shell_script_to_execute."' '".$jobtype."' '".
$REMOTE_USER."' '".$clientname."' '".$jobcommand."' '".$jobid."' '".
$servername."'  '".$rootaccess."'  ");

header("Location: https://192.168.42.78/operator/{$php_script_to_execute}?time=$time&jobname=$jobname&clientname=$clientname&groupname=$groupname");
```

What exactly does shell_exec function do?  and the header function?  Is header just a redirect?  What if  I have echo statements before that, will it redirect to the header page first and then display the echos?

Thanks

Comment: [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) and [`header`](http://php.net/header) are documented in the manual. What the purpose of their use here is can't be told with certainty without seeing the actual values, the shell script, or target page.

Answer (score 3):

The [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec) function executes a shell command and returns the command's output.

The [`header()`](http://php.net/header) function sets a HTTP header. The specific `Location` header causes the browser to redirect to the given URL. You should not output anything before using the header() function (or PHP won't be able to send the header).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're familiar with php.net, but these kind of questions you shouldn't ask here. Simply refer to the manual on http://php.net/docs.php

[shell_exec](http://php.net/shell_exec)

[header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)